# How to detect packets on mirrored port using Promiscuous mode on a VM running on Proxmox

Tags: ubuntu, wireshark, proxmox

I have a Proxmox server with four network ports eno1, eno2, eno3, eno4. The eno4 is used for management console and internet access using vmbr0 linux bridge. I have created a vmbr1 bridge for the port mirrored destination port eno1. But I am not able to see the traffic when I run Wireshark on promiscuous mode. I have set the VM ethernet port, eno1, vmbr1 in Promiscuous mode only. But still not able to detect the traffic from the source mirror ports.

[Proxmox network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLFyC.png)

[network and bridge ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOtiz.png)

[VM ethernet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZb2G.png)

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here for anyone else who finds this post as the solution worked for me.

The following will get you promiscuous traffic forwarded to other hosts on a bridge:

```
brctl setageing vmbr1 0
brctl setfd vmbr1 0
```

Source:
https://monach.us/operations/sending-promisc-traffic-within-proxmox/